# Spectral/ Eigen-Value solution with a linear constraint?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

Is there a spectral or eigen-value solution to finding $X$ such that $Tr(CX^TMX)$ is minimum for a symmetric matrix $C$ and a p.s.d matrix $M$. Also there is a linear constraint on the minimization that $TrX^TL=\lambda$ where $L$ is a given real matrix and $\lambda$ is a given real scalar.

If not what would be some solution to find $X$ that gives the minimum?